# Pass lambda to numerical library

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I am trying to use a numerical integration library that requires me to pass it a `double (*f)(double,void*)` as an argument. How can I pass it a lambda I create in the same scope? I tried

```
auto myLambda = [&](double d, void* data) { ... }
```

but the type of the lambda cannot be converted to the type required by the library. Is there an workaround?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably this library also lets you pass in the `data` argument with which the supplied function will be called. In that case, you can define a wrapper that treats that argument as a pointer to the actual object you want to call and forwards the call to that object, maybe something like this:

```
template <class F>
double function_for_library(double d, void* data) {
    F& f = *static_cast<F*>(data);
    return f(d);
}
```

Now if you have some arbitrary function object `f` of type `F` you can invoke the library like this:

```
invoke_library(function_for_library<F>, &f); // implicit conversion to void*
```

For a lambda you'll have to use `decltype` but it's no big deal.

```
auto myLambda = /* ... */;
invoke_library(function_for_library<decltype(myLambda)>, &myLambda);
```

Or you can write another wrapper that deduces the type.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class T>using type=T;
template<class F>
struct callback_t {
  F data;
  void* pdata(){return &data;}
  template<class R, class...Args>
  operator type<R(*)(Args...,void*)>()const{
    return [](Args...args,void*pdata)->R{
      F* data=static_cast<F*>(pdata);
      return (*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    };
  }
};
template<class F>
callback_t<F> callback(F f){
  return{std::move(f)};
}
```

use:

```
int scale=3;
auto cb = callback([&](double d){return d*scale;});
```

then pass `cb` in place of the function pointer, and `cb.pdata()` for the `void*` parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Only lambda **without** capture may decay to function pointer

I suspect that `void*` is the way to pass user data.
so you have to create a struct

```
struct Functor
{
    explicit Functor(capture_t&);

    void operator()(double d)
    {
         // Your stuff
    }

    static void call(double d, void* userdata)
    {
        (*reinterpret_cast<Functor*>(userdata))(d)
    }
private:
    capture_t m_capture
};
```

And then call

```
Functor func(capture);
library_function(&Functor::call, &func);
```